# MIME type mismatch Bootstrap/Scroll-out

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, mime

I'm designing a website on WordPress and I'm facing two errors to load bootstrap.js and ScrollOut.js :
- Blocked resources due to MIME type mismatch

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapjs', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '4.4.1', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('scrolloutjs', 'https://unpkg.com/scroll-out/dist/scroll-out.min.js', array(), '2.2.8', 'all');
```

Others js are loaded properly (fancybox, and my custom js).

How can I fix this please ?

Thank you

Comment: You're using `wp_enqueue_style` instead of `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: Thank you very much, it's ok now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `wp_enqueue_style` instead of `wp_enqueue_script`. Sometimes, it's the simple things that mess up our code ;)

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function. You need to use `wp_enqueue_script` for JavaScript files and `wp_enqueue_syles` for CSS files.

Here's the way your code should look:

```
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '4.4.1', 'all');
wp_enqueue_script('scrolloutjs', 'https://unpkg.com/scroll-out/dist/scroll-out.min.js', array(), '2.2.8', 'all');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Thank you, that's it ;)